# DataFrame error: “overloaded method value select with alternatives”

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I tried to create a new dataframe by select hour+minute/60 and other columns from a dataframe as follows:

```
val logon11 = logon1.select("User","PC","Year","Month","Day","Hour","Minute",$"Hour"+$"Minute"/60)
```

I got the error below:

```
<console>:38: error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
cannot be applied to (String, String, String, String, String, String, String,org.apache.spark.sql.Colum)

...
```

Maybe I have known the reason is that I cannot get a DataFrame with these types using "select" at the same time. Then how can I get such dataframe?

Comment: side note: If you missed to put "$" by accident in the select, It will give out the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `withColumn` create a new column from existing columns or based on some conditions like below

```
val logon1 = Seq(("User1","PC1",2017,2,12,12,10)).toDF("User","PC","Year","Month","Day","Hour","Minute")
val logon11 = logon1.withColumn("new_col", $"Hour"+$"Minute"/60)
logon11.printSchema()
logon11.show
```

output:

```
root
 |-- User: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PC: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Year: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Month: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Day: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Hour: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Minute: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- new_col: double (nullable = true)


+-----+---+----+-----+---+----+------+------------------+
| User| PC|Year|Month|Day|Hour|Minute|           new_col|
+-----+---+----+-----+---+----+------+------------------+
|User1|PC1|2017|    2| 12|  12|    10|12.166666666666666|
+-----+---+----+-----+---+----+------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 21):

DF's `select` method takes arguments of type either all `String`s or all `org.apache.spark.sql.Column`s but doesn't take mix of both.

In your case you are passing both `String` and `Column` type parameters to `select` method.

```
val logon11 = logon1.select($"User",$"PC",$"Year",$"Month",$"Day",$"Hour",$"Minute",$"Hour"+$"Minute"/60 as "total_hours")
```

Hope it helps!